# Как сделать вертикальный скроллинг блока?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Нужно добавлять скроллинг только тогда если нужен. Блок фиксированный, высота "auto"

Например: размер высоты экрана 768px, а блок 800px тогда нужно добавить скроллинг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что "Блок фиксированный" - это значит у него свойство "position: fixed;"?

[Тестируем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Q7WWd/1/).

```
var block = $('.fix_block');
function adjustmentBlock(){
    var winH = $(window).height();
    if(block.height() > winH){
        block.css({
            height: winH,
            overflowY: 'scroll'
        });
    } else {
        block.css({
            height: 'auto',
            overflowY: 'visible'
        });
    }
}
$(window).on('resize load', adjustmentBlock);
```

Comment: @Deonis, да все верно, а как изменить стили к нему ?

Comment: @Deonis, скролл-бара, например изменить размер и цвет ползунка

Comment: @Surfer, Это отдельная тема и в двух словах не описать. Ищите в гугле по запросу: "[стилизация скроллбара][1]" или "[кастомный скроллбар][2]"

   [1]:https://www.google.com/search?q=стилизация+скроллбара
   [2]:https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+scrollbar

Comment: @Deonis, ваш код у меня на компе почему-то не работает, именно сам скроллинг

Comment: @Surfer, что консоль говорит? Какая версия библиотеки? Обернули ли код в $(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ });

Comment: @Deonis, все заработало! просто что-то глючит библиотека <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Примените блоку свойства:

```
div {
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```